# ASDF optional system dependencies

Tags: common-lisp, asdf

I have a system I wrote that uses lparallel when possible, and otherwise works around it. Problem is, I'm now trying to test it on ECL, which errors upon merely loading lparallel.

Is  there a way (other than `#-ecl` ) to specify system dependencies parameterized by implementation type? I've looked at Madiera Port but it seems to work only for subcomponents, not system dependencies. I wish to keep my .asd file as a simple machine-readable form, without reader conditionals etc.

( aside: lparallel loads fine on a current ECL. mine was just outdated. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no direct way to do that in ASDF apart from reader conditionals. You could use XCVB instead, or write a `defsystem*` macro that adds new syntax, or (maybe) hook into the existing `defsystem` as madeira does.

Without knowing your motivation, I wonder why the simple solution of `#-ecl` is being avoided. Do you wish to store metadata that links ECL to the nonexistence of lparallel? Note `#-lparallel` and `#+lparallel` may be used in lisp files.

By the way lparallel loads fine for me in ECL. Are you running the latest ECL? There is a known bug in ECL that causes the lparallel tests to eventually hang, however this may not affect all platforms.

Comment: ah, thanks for the tip. my ECL is indeed outdated. I'm interested in keeping the defsystem form simple to support straightforward external tooling.